# how to add recently compared products in a div

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add recently compared products in a div. so I added this code in CMS

```
<div id="contents_right" style="background-color: green; float: right; width: 250px; height: 100%;">
    &nbsp; 
{{widget type="reports/product_widget_compared" page_size="5" template="reports/widget/compared/content/compared_list.phtml"}}
</div>
```

But I cannot see any widget added in my homepage. Where have I gone wrong?
Thanks..

Comment: Please clear magento cache if enable and try to add some product in compare. I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i'm using same widget code in my local magento 1.9 and i have result on my home cms page.
to so recently compared product first of all you need to add product  to add to compare.
after that you have compared product list/grid  display on your home page.
will you please there have any display:none style on id="contents_right"?? if have that style then please remove that.
[image]

[image]